# Whenever I apply autocomplete.js the input text box will change Algolia

Tags: algolia

Im using algolia to perform a search on my website, but I realized one thing. Im using [search box generator](http://shipow.github.io/searchbox/) to customized my search input field. However the problems occur, when I try to apply autocomplete.js on my search input field
Initially, it looks like the one below, 
[image]

but when I apply the autocomplete feature it will look like this

[image]

Code - HTML

```
<form id="search" novalidate="novalidate" onsubmit="return false;" class="searchbox sbx-google" style="margin-top: 7px;">
        <div role="search" class="sbx-google__wrapper">
          <input type="search" id="search_input" name="search" placeholder="Search" autocomplete="off" required="required" class="sbx-google__input">
          <button type="submit" title="Submit your search query." class="sbx-google__submit">
            <svg role="img" aria-label="Search">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-search-13"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button type="reset" title="Clear the search query." class="sbx-google__reset">
            <svg role="img" aria-label="Reset">
              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#sbx-icon-clear-3"></use>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Code - JAVASCRIPT

```
  autocomplete('#search_input',
{ hint: false }, {
    source: autocomplete.sources.hits(index, {hitsPerPage: 5}),
    //value to be displayed in input control after user's suggestion selection
    displayKey: 'name',
    //hash of templates used when rendering dataset
    templates: {
        //'suggestion' templating function used to render a single suggestion
        suggestion: function(suggestion) {
          console.log(suggestion)
          return '<span>' +
            suggestion._highlightResult.title.value + '</span>';
        }
    }
});
```

The custom search box is advised by algolia themselves, on the [autocomplete documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/search/auto-complete/#introductionHere). I have no idea on how to solve this problem, seems like the js script overwrite the css styling. This only happen if I passed in the `#search_input` in the autocomplete function

Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpqhkam/

Comment: Can you post a link to your website if it's online please?

Comment: It may be that the CSS rules you are using or the ones from the searchbox generator are no more applied when autocomplete.js is used. A live link could help yes (like a jsfiddle, jsbin or codepen)

Comment: Here is the js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Ldpqhkam/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algolia autocomplete adds a `span` around the `input` and that's what breaks the design. It has inline style changing the display, you can override it to fix the design.

```
.algolia-autocomplete {
  display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Julien! didn't know it was a pretty simple problem, I thought I need to go through the js code.

Comment: You're welcome :) I thought it would be more complicated when I looked at it